# ListLogPlot with uncertainties in both coordinates

Tags: list-manipulation, logarithmic-scale, around

I have a  dataset like this:

```
data = 
  {{3.17, 2.41*^10}, {4.43, 2.37*^10}, {5.54, 2.27*^10}, {6.87, 2.15*^10}, 
   {8.52, 1.98*^10}, {10.5, 1.85*^10}, {13.14, 1.8*^10},{14.74, 1.81*^10}};
```

and I want to plot them via `ListLogPlot`.

Now, I would like to show 10% uncertainty in `x` and 5% uncertainty in `y`. I know, I can use the `Around` function for this. Written out by hand it looks like this:

```
data2 = 
  {{Around[3.17, Scaled[0.1]], Around[2.41*^10, Scaled[0.05]]}, 
   {Around[4.43, Scaled[0.1]], Around[2.37*^10, Scaled[0.05]]}, 
   {Around[5.54, Scaled[0.1]], Around[2.27*^10, Scaled[0.05]]}, 
   {Around[6.87, Scaled[0.1]], Around[2.15*^10, Scaled[0.05]]}, 
   {Around[8.52, Scaled[0.1]], Around[1.98*^10, Scaled[0.05]]}, 
   {Around[10.5, Scaled[0.1]], Around[1.85*^10, Scaled[0.05]]}, 
   {Around[13.14, Scaled[0.1]], Around[1.8*^10, Scaled[0.05]]}, 
   {Around[14.74, Scaled[0.1]], Around[1.81*^10, Scaled[0.05]]}};
```

With `ListLogPlot[data2]`, I get the a plot:

[image]

Is there any way to automatize the definition of the 2nd dataset? My actual datssets are much larger, and I have many of them. I assume something like `Map` could be used.

I'm open for any idea. Maybe there is even a more elegant way directly in the `ListLogPlot` function.

Comment: Using `ReplaceAll`, consider: `data /. {x_, y_} :> {Around[x, Scaled[0.1]], Around[y, Scaled[0.05]]}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) for this. Like so:

```
data = 
  {{3.17, 2.41*^10}, {4.43, 2.37*^10}, {5.54, 2.27*^10}, {6.87, 2.15*^10}, 
   {8.52, 1.98*^10}, {10.5, 1.85*^10}, {13.14, 1.8*^10},{14.74, 1.81*^10}};
MapThread[{Around[#1, Scaled[0.1]], Around[#2, Scaled[0.05]]} &, Transpose[data]]
```

> ```
> {{3.17 ± 0.32, (2.41±0.12)×10^10}, {4.4±0.4, (2.37±0.12)×10^10},
>  {5.5±0.6, (2.27±0.11)×10^10}, {6.9±0.7, (2.15±0.11)×10^10},
>  {8.5±0.9, (1.98±0.10)×10^10}, {10.5±1.1, (1.85±0.09)×10^10},
>  {13.1±1.3, (1.80±0.09)×10^10}, {14.7±1.5, (1.81±0.09)×10^10}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[threadAround]
threadAround = Thread @* MapThread[Thread[Around[#, Scaled @ #2]] &]@{Transpose[#], #2} &;
```

***Example:***

```
data = {{3.17, 2.41*^10}, {4.43, 2.37*^10}, {5.54, 2.27*^10}, {6.87, 2.15*^10},
  {8.52, 1.98*^10}, {10.5, 1.85*^10}, {13.14, 1.8*^10}, {14.74, 1.81*^10}};

threadAround[data, {.1, .05}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ClearAll[threadAround2]
threadAround2[d_, s_] := MapThread[Thread[Around[{##}, Scaled /@ s]] &]@Transpose[d]

threadAround2[data, {.1, .05}] == threadAround[data, {.1, .05}]
```

> True

Comment: I like the idea with the function. But I don't understand your `threadAround2`, this function produces asymmetric errors.